# SAS EG: SAS Dataset is locked by opening it from EG. Need a resolution

Tags: sas

One of the critical SAS dataset is left open from SAS Enterprise Guide, by our offshore associate. We are depending on that dataset for many updates through various jobs. I tried searching for an option from various sites to unlock the dataset, but of no use. Kindly provide any suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: Ask your offshore associate to close out of SAS.

Comment: Assuming you're asking because that's not possible, you need to provide more information than that.  Server environment or desktop SAS EG (with local copy)?  What OS is the server that hosts the dataset (or otherwise, what filesystem)?  How is your offshore associate connecting in?

Comment: And what dbms are you using? SAS or Oracle?

Comment: @Joe : Yes, reaching out to offshore associate is tough at this moment. Our SAS environment is on Linux platform. We can open the dataset from the respective library by just double click on the dataset name from the SAS EG.

Comment: I would assume you can log/disconnect the user from your Linux system and that would unlock the dataset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on some of the specifics of your situation, another option is to prevent **anyone** from locking it in the first place using a `PW=` dataset option like:

```
data myImportantTable(PW=pass123);
    x=1;output;
run;
```

Then you could create a view that allows EG users to click and see the underlying data, but does not LOCK the original dataset:

```
proc sql; 
    CREATE VIEW myImportantTable_view AS
    SELECT * FROM myImportantTable(read=pass123)
;quit;
```

Now INSERTS, UPDATES etc will work even if the view is opened by a user in EG:

```
*This will work even if view is opened in EG;
proc sql;
    INSERT INTO myImportantTable(PW=pass123) VALUES(101)
;quit;
```

Note that this is not a good option if you've got a lot of different INSERT/UPDATE statements spread throughout your program - each of them would need the `(PW=...)` dataset option added to them in order to work.

Comment: Thank you Tim. We dont have those many updates and inserts even though the dataset is critical. This workds for us.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [SYSTASK](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/hostwin/63285/HTML/default/viewer.htm#win-stmt-systask.htm) command to execute a `mv` (move) or `cp` (copy) UNIX command to replace the existing data set. If you need to move or copy more than one data set at a time you can use the `*` wildcard but you must also use the `SHELL` option.

Answer (score 0):

There is an option in SAS Enterprise Guide. Under Tools --> Options --> Data --> Performance. There is a check box, "Close Data Grid after period of inactivity (in minutes)" This was even if the data grid is opened after 'n' minutes, it will be available for others to update.